# How can I match two frequencies in advanced design system software (ADS). I want to match 2.45 GHz and 915 MHz with a 50 ohm source and 1.5 kohm load

Tags: rf

How can I match two frequencies in advanced design system software (ADS). I want to match 2.45 GHz and 915 MHz with a 50 Ω source and 1.5 kΩ load. When I tried matching I am only getting result for the second frequency that I have matched.

---

[image: This is the design in ADS.]

This is the design in ADS.

Comment: Dual band matching can be very tricky. Did you try and design it for the two bands. If so, then show the design.

Comment: That's a huge impedance ratio, that will be tricky to match with just Ls, Cs and line at one frequency, let alone two. It won't be straightforward with a transformer either.

Comment: suraj s kumar - Hi, Your "answer" (which wasn't an answer to your original question, & therefore should not have been posted in the "Your Answer" box) has been added to the question instead as an edit i.e. an update. Unless you are writing the *full and final* answer to your own question (i.e. unless you have solved the problem yourself, with no further help needed) please don't use the "Your Answer" box below. Instead, you should edit the question to add new info. This is an example of how Stack Exchange is different from typical forums. See the [tour] and [help] for more rules. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have an independent signal source for each frequency, or a single, common, tunable signal signal source?

Comment: Single common source